# Maintain two different model schema version to connect two different database in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my Django app, I have one model `Question` which is connected to database `db_one`.

Now I want add and modify few fields in `Question` model. Until the new `Question` model schema is tested thoroughly, I want to keep the old `Question` model schema accessible in UI. Also I am maintaining a separate database `db_two` for this new schema such that main app is not affected.

How can model schema versioning be achieved in Django such that I could select the database based on model version?

Or, Is there any better approach to deal with this?

Comment: Why not name the new model `NewQuestion`, and thus perform some modifications, and later rename it to `Question`. I think the database in which it ist stored is not that important here.

Comment: You can use [DB router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Do you mean to create a duplicate `Question` model with name `NewQuestion`?

Comment: @cezar Yes.. DB router can be used, but there should be some differentiating factor between two models. In this case, app is same (In the link `app_label` is used in condition). So I was looking for if we can somehow version the models schema (not records ) in Django

Comment: Yes, that was my point. Create another `test` or `development` app where you duplicate the model `Question`. In the end it's not much different from the idea of @WillemVanOnsem.

Comment: If you want to keep just one model, than you could apply the migrations to the production DB and development DB. Then, when you change something in the model that is not yet ready for production, make migration and apply it only to the development DB. This could be tricky, but that's the first thing that strikes me.